# How to display JFrame application in browser without Applets

Tags: java, swing, deployment, jframe, applet

I'm currently developing a 3D game in Java using `JFrame`. I want to make the program playable through a browser, which I had heard could be done using the `Applet` class. However, I've just discovered that the `Applet` class has been deprecated!

What alternatives, if any, are there to Applets for making `JFrame` based applications available in-browser?

Comment: *"What alternatives, if any, are there to Applets for making JFrame based applications available in-browser?"* There aren't any. It used to be possible to launch a `JFrame` using Java Web Start, but that depends on the exact same Java Plug-In that browser makers ceased to support due to security concerns. See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).

Comment: [tag:java-web-start]?

Comment: @CatalinaIsland *"java-web-start?"* No! It's mentioned in my comment (as also being defunct / deprecated).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Thanks for responding. I thought it might still be useful outside the browser, but I see it's [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score -2):

A JFrame cannot be displayed within a browser.

What you can do is to put your GUI on a JPanel which you should be able to add to either a JFrame or a JApplet by invoking setContentPanne(yiur_panel_here).

JApplets (and AWT Applets can be displayed by a Java-enabled browser.

Comment: Except the applet plugin is deprecated and is actively blocked or disabled by most browsers or is planned to be - Applets are effectively dead

Comment: Isn't the question all about "without Applets" ?